# TFS Build Agent sporadically goes offline on TFS server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2018 on-premise server with a separate build server. The build server has VS 2017 installed. On random occasions the build agent will reflect offline on the TFS server. The service for the build agent is running. In order to get the agent online, I must restart the agent using run.cmd. It appears a permission issue is causing the problem but I cannot determine why or how. I see no issue in Credentials Manager. I can restart the agent and builds will run without issue.

The *agent log file* has a notation of HTTP 401 error. At the bottom of the agent log there is TF400813 "Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required" message

The **worker log file** has no warning or errors.

**From Agent Log**:

> [2018-10-29 20:51:48Z INFO RSAEncryptedFileKeyManager] Loading RSA key
>   parameters from file D:\CI\credentials_rsaparams [2018-10-29 20:51:48Z
>   INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Connecting to the server. [2018-10-29
>   20:51:48Z INFO MessageListener] Attempt to create session. [2018-10-29
>   20:51:48Z INFO MessageListener] Connecting to the Agent Server...
>   [2018-10-29 20:51:48Z INFO VisualStudioServices] **Starting operation
>   Location.GetConnectionData [2018-10-29 20:51:48Z WARN
>   VisualStudioServices] Authentication failed with status code 401**.
>
> P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi
>   BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT" Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/10.0 WWW-Authenticate: Bearer, Basic
>   realm="http://server:8080/tfs", Negotiate, NTLM X-TFS-ProcessId:
>   997a2986-a08c-4cc1-86e2-e1e30513c61a ActivityId:
>   c728a277-0b76-46c1-b3f5-d1e7afb979b4 X-TFS-Session:
>   40cecbac-588b-4ee4-bad4-f3a34d7f068d X-VSS-E2EID:
>   73cd4d47-4149-41a1-b0c5-c82e53afd82a X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
>   X-TFS-SoapException:
>   %3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3Csoap%3AEnvelope%20xmlns%3Asoap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F05%2Fsoap-envelope%22%3E%3Csoap%3ABody%3E%3Csoap%3AFault%3E%3Csoap%3ACode%3E%3Csoap%3AValue%3Esoap%3AReceiver%3C%2Fsoap%3AValue%3E%3Csoap%3ASubcode%3E%3Csoap%3AValue%3EUnauthorizedRequestException%3C%2Fsoap%3AValue%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ASubcode%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ACode%3E%3Csoap%3AReason%3E%3Csoap%3AText%20xml%3Alang%3D%22en%22%3ETF400813%3A%20Resource%20not%20available%20for%20anonymous%20access.%20Client%20authentication%20required.%3C%2Fsoap%3AText%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AReason%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AFault%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ABody%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AEnvelope%3E
>   **X-TFS-ServiceError: TF400813%3A%20Resource%20not%20available%20for%20anonymous%20access.%20Client%20authentication%20required.**
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Lfs-Authenticate: NTLM X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff

**Update:**

I do notice a Powershell message in event viewer occurring at the same time the build server logs note an issue with authentication. I attached the message. I am not sure if the Powershell warning is caused by the agent issue or if Powershell is causing the agent issue.

[Powershell Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ro67.jpg)

Comment: When you installed the agent did you installed him "as a service" with the username and password?

Comment: Yes the agent is installed as a service with the username and password.